# DetailsView Insert default value for checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, insert, default, detailsview

I have a big DetailsView form for an insert to a database and I have a lot (10+) checkbox fields. Many of them aren't visible because we don't want those fields activated yet to have data submitted (but may be activated in the future).

How I can set the default value of all checkboxes at first to "false" (unchecked)? As of right now, they are being inserted as nulls and that doesn't play too well with everything else.

So far I have this code behind running as an onDataBound event for the DetailsView:

```
Dim row As DetailsViewRow
    For Each row In DetailsView1A.Rows
        If row.Cells.GetType() = GetType(CheckBox) Then
           Dim tempCheckbox As CheckBox = CType(row.Cells(1).Controls(0), CheckBox)
           If tempCheckbox Is DBNull.Value Then
              tempCheckbox.Checked = False
           End If
        End If
     Next
```

However, all the checkboxes are still being submitted as nulls. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `If tempCheckbox Is DBNull.Value Then
` condition?

Comment: @jadarnel27 I just tried that, doesn't work either. What does work is if I put in all the checkboxes into the page with Visible='true'. However, I don't want those fields there yet but the ones that remain hidden are left as null.

Comment: This is not a programming answer, but you could just set the default value of those specific columns to false within the particular RDBMS you're using (SQL Server, presumably). That way, if no value is specified, you'll end up with "false".

Comment: @jadarnel27 unfortunately I am only an intern for the company and my manager really doesn't want to change the structure of the database because of potential side-effects on reporting services, other connections, etc.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I had a thought for a way you can work around this (which I poasted as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the `ItemInserting` event, and updating the "Values" collection of the DetailsViewInsertEventArgs object.  These are the values that will be passed to your datasource's insert statement.

Go through and update the "Values" entry for each of these hidden CheckBox columns to `False`.  Here's is an example:

```
Sub CustomerDetail_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewInsertEventArgs)
    e.Values("yourFieldName") = False
End Sub
```

Note that "yourFieldName" will be the name of the column in the datasource to which the DetailsView is connected.

Also, False might need to be a string, I'm not sure how this actually gets passed:

```
e.Values("yourFieldName") = "False"
```

---

One other thought: if the above doesn't work (for some reason those hidden CheckBoxes don't have entries in the Values collection), I would just not hide them on the server side - hide them using CSS or JavaScript.  In other words, instead of having `Visible="False"` on your CheckBox, use the CSS property `display:none`.

Comment: I'll try this first thing tomorrow. Is there anyway to iterate through the DetailsView though? It would be better to loop through, check if the control is a checkbox and if so and its null, then set to false. It takes less maintenaince after I leave in case so they don't have to manually remove lines should they want to activate certain fields. Thanks for all the help by the way!

Comment: @user2516794 Did this work out for you?  FYI - you probably *could* do something like what you described, but it would be funky in that context.  You would want to put that same loop you have in your question inside this Sub I wrote.  Then, inside that loop, check the values against the visible CheckBoxes that you find in your loop.  Does that make sense?